# firstElementChild doesn't work in Internet Explorer 7...what are my options?

Tags: javascript

Consider the JavaScript below:

```
var v;
if (this.children.length > 0) {
    v = this.firstElementChild.value;
}
```

This works in modern versions of FireFox and Chrome but `this.firstElementChild.value` throws an exception in Internet Explorer 7-8.  Is there another way for me to get this to work for all browsers?

### **UPDATE -- FINAL SOLUTION**

I went with the following:

`v = (this.firstElementChild || this.children[0] || {}).value` --Thanks to all.

Comment: The `|| {}` doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know, maybe `this.children[0].value`?

Comment: FF 3.0 doesn't support `children`, so you may need something like `( this.firstElementChild || this.children[0] ).value`. Also, IE counts comment nodes in `children`.

Comment: ...or for safety: `( this.firstElementChild || this.children[0] || {} ).value`

Comment: Using `(something || {}).value` looks pointless to me. `({}).value` will always be `undefined`.

Answer (score 8):

`this.firstElementChild` should work in every significant browser bar IE <=9 and Firefox 3 ([QuirksMode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t81)).

`this.children[0]` will work in every significant browser bar Firefox 3, except that IE <=9 counts comment nodes as element nodes ([QuirksMode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t71)). This may or may not be an issue for you.

The catch-all system is this:

```
var node = this.firstChild,
    firstElementChild = null;

for ( ; node; node = node.nextSibling) {
    if (node.nodeType === 1) {
        firstElementChild = node;
        break;
    }
}
```

`firstElementChild` will then be the first element child if one exists, `null` otherwise. It would be best to see if `this.firstElementChild` exists before doing the loop, for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is in an event handler and the function is bound with "attachEvent" the "this" keyword is bound to the "window" object and not the HTMLElement.
Try:

```
function doSomething(e) {
    var targ;
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    if (e.target) targ = e.target;
    else if (e.srcElement) targ = e.srcElement;
    if (targ.nodeType == 3) // defeat Safari bug
        targ = targ.parentNode;
}
```

Check http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html.

Answer (score 0):

try the following :

```
var v;
if (this.children.length > 0) {
    v = this.firstChild;
}
```

althogh in modern browsers first child will usually will be text segment

Answer (score 0):

We ran into this problem with IE11 and discovered that .firstChild() is a reliable fix across all browsers.

Comment: Please see this first [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Thanks. May I ask why?

Comment: This question is answered before, obviously, you can add your answer here. But You Need to understand some points before answering. First, don't add an answer which is previously added with the same code or suggestion. Second, don't add an overly complicated answer if the user has asked very specifically about the problem and what he needs to solve this. Third, You can add a comment if you want to suggest anything regarding the answer or question.