# Get a child element tag in html using Javascript in the onclick attribute

Tags: javascript, html

Using pure javascript, I want to reference the first inner html element within an `<a>` element, by using the parent's `onclick` attribute. I tried to use both `firstChild` and `firstChild.InnerHTML`, but I could not get my element.

For example, the following html code:

```
<a href="#" onclick="showImg(this.firstChild.innerHTML)">
  <img src="imgs/placeholder.png" alt="My Image" title="image-name" >
  <p>This is a paragraph</p>
  <div>This is a div</div>
</a>
```

I want to get the `<img>` element as a parameter into the function `showImg()`,
so I can obtain the title attribute to feed into an image path to be displayed in a modal window/popup.

The same modal window would be displayed using the same function, BTW.

Is this possible to achieve?
(Please note that I want to grab the entire element, not just an attribute.)

Doing this because there is no permission to add jquery or other similar libraries.

UPDATE: I am looking for code that works on IE from version 7 upward.

MY SOLUTION:
I finally ended using the getAttribute method, after combining both first `firstElementChild` and `children[0]` as per details from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6333249/1960071).

My final solution looks like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" 
   onclick="showImg((this.firstElementChild || 
                     this.children[0]).getAttribute('title'))">
  <img src="imgs/placeholder.png" alt="My Image" title="image-name" >
  <p>This is a paragraph</p>
  <div>This is a div</div>
</a>
```

And this is the script:

```
  function getImg(img) {        
    var container = document.getElementById("some-id");
    var imgPath = 'imgs/' +img+ '.png';
    container.src = imgPath;
  }
```

Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```js
function showImg(image) {
  console.log(image);
  }
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="showImg(this.children[0].getAttribute('title'))">
  <img src="imgs/placeholder.png" alt="My Image" title="image-name" >
  <p>This is a paragraph</p>
  <div>This is a div</div>
</a>
```

If you want the whole element, replace the onclick with:
`onclick="showImg(this.children[0])"`

Comment: Same as for [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33003741/1960071), I want to grab the entire element, not just an attribute. (I would deal with the attribute within the called function.)

Comment: I updated it...just remove getAttribute from the children[0] object and you've got the element object.

Comment: Ok, will test it as soon as I get another issue fixed.

Comment: Ok, I ended up modifying my code so as to just use the title attribute. And this served me well in the purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `getAttribute` function

```
<a href="#" onclick="showImg(this.firstElementChild.getAttribute('title')">
```

Comment: This will not work, as a firstChild is a Node object, which does not have access to getAttribute();

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I think I did not explain myself properly:
I want to grab the entire element, not just an attribute.
I would deal with the attribute within the called function. Thanks.

Comment: Uh, I forgot to mention that it should support IE from v. 7 upward,

Answer (score 2):

Use this.firstElementChild.outerHTML

```
<a href="#" onclick="alert(this.firstElementChild.outerHTML)">
  <img src="imgs/placeholder.png" alt="My Image" title="image-name" >
  <p>This is a paragraph</p>
  <div>This is a div</div>
</a>
```